# Automatically set relation when posting object in nested router uri

Tags: django, rest, post, django-rest-framework

Using [drf-extensions](http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/) I was able to achieve nested routes to be able to access related objects using the pattern /users/{pk}/comments. While that works alright I want to find a way to create objects using that URI where the foreign key will be set automatically to the parent object specified in {pk}. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5):

There is an issue on the [github repository](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/15). 
For now the recommended approach is [explicit implementation](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/15#issuecomment-47745649) of this logic:

```
# viewsets
from rest_framework_extensions.utils import compose_parent_pk_kwarg_name


class CommentViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    pass


class UserCommentViewSet(NestedViewSetMixin, CommentViewSet):
    def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        user_pk = getattr(self, compose_parent_pk_kwarg_name('user_comments'))
        request.DATA['user'] = user_pk
        return super(UserCommentViewSet, self).create(request, *args, **kwargs)


# routers
router = ExtendedSimpleRouter()

router.register(r'comments', CommentViewSet)
(
    router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, base_name='user')
          .register(r'comments',
                    UserCommentViewSet,
                    base_name='users-comments',
                    parents_query_lookups=['user_comments'])
)
```